# Rewrite with relative path

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am going nuts over a reqrite rule on my local machine...

i even enabled the rewrite log and this is what i get from a single page load on the url it should rewrite:

```
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/ArticleSearch/SearchEngine/GetInitialData
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/(.+)/(\w+)/(\w+?)$' to uri '/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/ArticleSearch/SearchEng$
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (2) rewrite '/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/ArticleSearch/SearchEngine/GetInitialData' -> '/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/handler.php?pa$
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (3) split uri=/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/handler.php?path=ArticleSearch&class=SearchEngine&method=GetInitialData -> uri=/catde$
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (2) local path result: /catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/handler.php
ip - - [21/May/2013:08:13:18 +0200] [scxx/sid#7f6580ce32b8][rid#7f65810069e0/initial] (1) go-ahead with /catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/handler.php [OK]
```

The path gets found correctly, but it still dous not load the page it should. i have NO idea why!

the error log shows me this.

```
[Tue May 21 08:13:18 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] File does not exist: /catdev/sc/eprocure
```

Now i have theese rewrite rules i my apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.at
        ServerName xxx
        DocumentRoot /data1/www/somewherefarbeyond/ssl-htdocs

        <Directory /data1/www/somewherefarbeyond/ssl-htdocs/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /data1/www/somewherefarbeyond/logs/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /data1/www/somewherefarbeyond/logs/access.log combined


        RewriteEngine On
         RewriteRule ^/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/(.+)/(\w+)/(\w+?)$      /catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/handler.php?path=$1&class=$2&method=$3 [L]
        RewriteLog /data1/www/somewherefarbeyond/logs/accessREWRITE.log
        RewriteLogLevel 9

</VirtualHost>
```

Can somone shred some light into this thing?

he url im trying is xxx/catdev/sc/eprocure/ajax/ArticleSearch/SearchEngine/GetInitialData

note xxx  is hand owerwriten doman from my dev server and ips are obscurified to.

Comment: Strangly when i add the redirect url as an absolute url it gets redirected. but externally, not internally sadly Q_Q... anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

God damn it.

Iw was a debian "Feature"

I work on a debian distro, and there for some wierd reason when you make the rewrites in the base config you have to specify the whole DIRECTORY path not the relative path.

Just make the rewriten url a directory location NOT a url!

example is:

your www folder is in

```
/motherofGod/wtf/www
```

your www root is set to `/motherofGod/wtf/www` in the apatche

Your domain is lols.com

so the file `lols.com/lol/wtf`

which needs to to on to `/motherofGod/wtf/www/some/crap/handler.php`

ou have to specify the WHOLE path not just the relative path from the www directory ~_~